# Spring Boot with Jaeger tracing but no REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaeger

I have a Spring boot Kafka Consumer project. It listens to a topic and does not have any Rest Contoller as such. Would like to add Jager or OTEL traceability to my project? Is it possible?

I have added pom.xml dependency in springboot 2.7.2 and also pointing to Jaeger collector url from applications.properties. But nothing comes up on Jaeger UI

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.